# open local html file with navigateToURL on android & ios

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I have created an HTML file and I want to show it with navigateToUrl method:

```
var htmlFile:File = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath("WebWin//Factor//" + "Factor" + ".html");
var fs:FileStream = new FileStream();
fs.open(htmlFile, FileMode.WRITE);
fs.writeUTFBytes(htmlString);
fs.close();
if(htmlFile.exists)
{
   navigateToURL(new URLRequest(htmlFile.url), "_blank"); 
}
```

but on Android or iOS I can't open HTML file (I don't have any issue on windows)

[image]

this is htmlFile.url :

```
file///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/AB199919-1E41-47E7-9716-DA5CD746D113/Documents/WebWin/Factor/Factor.html
```

Also for URLRequet url, I tried other ways like("http://"+htmlFile.url) but I wasn't successful.

Do me a big favor if you help me

Comment: Figure out the correct URL form that mobile browser supports.

Comment: Or rather use **htmlFile.nativePath** to form the **URLRequest**.