# How to open local html files in safari?

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I want to show the **local** HTML file in Safari because my users are able to send their HTML files as a PDF in the options menu

[image]

For this reason:

```
var htmlFile:File = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath("WebWin//invoice//" + "billing.html");
if(htmlFile.exist)
{
trace("logo is exist")
navigateToURL(new URLRequest(htmlFile.url), "_blank");
}
```

didn't work on mobile devices (works only on Windows)

also when I share local HTML files with Share ANE,

```
Share.service.shareFile( htmlFile.url, "html.html", "text/html" );
```

on iOS, it doesn't show Safari, or when I select Chrome, it prompts me Chrome cannot handle this link!

can you help me, how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Did you try what I advised on your previous question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65807851/open-local-html-file-with-navigatetourl-on-android-ios

Comment: Yes, of course, I try this way and also other ways but my problem still remains...

Comment: it's quite possible that Android and iOS are more locked down, and they simply won't allow local HTML files to be opened in their web browsers.